# Synonyme de « charmante »

Tags: choix-de-mot, vocabulaire

J'adore le mot *charmant* mais je l'emploie tellement souvent que je voudrais en trouver un vrai synonyme. Je ne suis pas francophone et je dois me fier d'habitude aux dictionnaires mais c'est des fois difficile de dire si le mot alternatif est utilisé dans le langage courant.

J'aimerais insister sur le sens du mot. Pour moi, une personne charmante, *e.g.* une fille charmante, est quelqu'un qui est potentiellement beau ou belle mais surtout dont la personnalité est très attirante. De plus, dire à quelqu'un « tu es charmant(e) » a un petit aspect romantique.

La meilleure alternative que j'ai pu trouver serait probablement l'adjectif *ravissant*. Mais il me semble que *être ravissant* est lié principalement à la beauté au niveau de l'apparence, ce qui ne serait pas suffisant car ça ne touche pas à la personnalité.

Auriez-vous une idée pour remplacer *charmant* tout en gardant le même sens ?

Comment: Tu écris dans un français des meilleurs, on veut peut-être bien savoir pourquoi tu ne cherches pas juste dans un dictionnaire (unilingue) de synonymes :·) (J'aime la question, à part ça : +1 quand j'aurai de nouveau des votes.)

Comment: Merci, c'est bien gentil. J'ai déjà essayé les dictionnaires mais comme je l'avait précisé, les dictionnaires ne sont pas toujours clairs quant à l'usage courant du mot. Par exemple, j'ai le mot _captivant_ qui est donné comme synonyme mais est-ce qu'un natif le comprendrait comme je le voudrais?.. :)

Comment: Est-ce que je peux t'inviter [sur le chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette), pour préserver cette pauvre page d'incessants commentaires ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je propose :

- ***Adorable*** si tu veux insister sur l'affection.
- ***Enchanteresse*** si tu veux plutôt aller vers la terrible séduction à laquelle tu succombes. (Ça rime avec *tigresse*.)

Le [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/charmant) en propose une paire, mais je ne les aime pas tellement, pour la plupart.

- *agréable* : Sonne objectif, et pas très humain.
- *aimable* : *Vous êtes bien brave*, mais l'attirance est ailleurs.
- *attrayant* : *Moi vouloir toi*, et le mystère aux oubliettes.
- *plaisant* : Idéal pour parler d'une femme-objet.
- *ravissant* : Tu en parles bien.
- *séduisant* : Au moins, c'est franc.
- [*amène*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/am%25C3%25A8ne) : Qui est agréable, au sens moral, aimable. Certes.
- *enchanteur* : Ça c'est joli :·)

Si tu veux des listes de mots pour t'inspirer [en](http://www.mediadico.com/dictionnaire/synonymes/charmant) [voilà](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/charmant/) [quelques](http://www.synonymes.com/synonyme.php?mot=charmant) [unes](http://www.synonymo.fr/synonyme/charmant).

Comment: J'aime bien _enchanteresse_. Est-ce que ça pourrait être mal compris? Car ce mot a également une connotation plutôt négative. Mais j'avoue que je l'ai jamais entendu avant (j'habite en Belgique).

Comment: Je ne pense pas, mais je ne vois pas vraiment la connotation dont tu parles (à part le *terrible* que j'indique moi-même, mais qui reste plus du ressort de la glose que du véritable sens). Après, je suis peut-être biaisé par l'opposition *enchantement*/*malédiction* des RPG, au bénéfice des premiers. Et bien sûr, si toi tu penses que ça pourrait être mal compris, alors quelqu'un d'autre peut effectivement mal le comprendre. Reste à savoir si ça fait beaucoup de monde.

Answer (score 0):

Selon Le Bon Synonyme, site qui classe les synonymes selon les votes des visiteurs, voici le top 5 des synonymes de "charmant" :

1. ravissant (3 votes)
2. gracieux (3 votes)
3. séduisant (3 votes)
4. plaisant (2 votes)
5. attirant (2 votes)

Source : [lebonsynonyme.fr](https://lebonsynonyme.fr/synonyme/charmant)

Answer (score -1):

BCBG ? (Beau Cul Belle Gueule)

Certains mots n'ont pas de synonymes qui correspondent exactement. Ma réponse serait de te dire qu'il faudrait voir à choisir le mot en fonction du contexte.

Nikana propose *enchanteresse* (*enchanteur*) qui de mon point de vue est [très] négatif (méchante sorcière).

Le mieux serait sinon d'utiliser une phrase, plutôt qu'un mot.

Formel :

> J'ai beaucoup aimé (ou apprécié) te rencontrer (aujourd'hui).

Moins formel :

> C'était super de faire ta connaissance.

Ou encore :

> J'espère que l'on pourra se revoir bientôt.

Note que de mon point de vue, dire à quelqu'un qu'il (elle) est charmant(e) est déjà assez fort (début de drague).

Comment: J'aime bien l'intensité avec laquelle BCBG *extermine* le petit aspect romantique. Pour *enchanteresse*, j'aimerais vraiment savoir quelles zones géographiques le voient négativement, mais pensez à la formule « Enchanté » en faisant la connaissance de quelqu'un : ça n'est pas si terrible, quand même ? Il y a une forte nuance avec *sorcière* ; on pourra dire quand même dire qu'on est *ensorcelé* pour dire qu'on est amoureux, mais ça peut avoir la connotation (mauvaise) qu'on dépend de la personne et qu'on arrive pas à s'en défaire, sans forcément que ça soit réciproque.

Comment: Et pour revenir sur *enchanter*, si je dis que quelque chose est arrivé *comme par enchantement*, c'est généralement positif, que je sache. (Je veux bien la confirmation d'autres francophones, pour le coup.)

Comment: Ah oui. « Enchanté(e) » c'est bien aussi. C'est intéressant qu'au contraire le nom soit (de mon point de vue) aussi négatif. Je suis de l'est de la France, à propos de l'aspect géographique. Maintenant... « charmant » et « enchanté » pose un problème car le sujet change (tu es / je suis). C'est une nuance importante quand même.

Comment: Oui, pour moi aussi, _comme par enchantement_ sonne positif. Je suppose que enchanteresse est une référence aux _sorcières_ du moyen age. Le mot masculin ne sonne pas aussi négatif (comme _merlin l'enchanteur_). Problème de culture je suppose.

Comment: _Certains mots n'ont pas de synonymes qui correspondent exactement_. C'est amusant, pour moi, *aucun mot* n'a de synonyme parfait.

Comment: BCBG = **bon chic bon genre**